# Get the Rect property of a UI object inside a Canvas that has the HorizontalLayoutGroup Component

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a Canvas that has a `HorizontalLayoutGroup` component. Inside this canvas there are three objects: a panel and two buttons. The arrangement is such that the buttons are on the sides and the panel is in the middle.

During execution I need the `RectTransform.rect.x` and `RectTransform.rect.y` properties of the two buttons. I have tried in different ways, but in all I always get the same values ​​(as if the objects were overlapped). I suspect that it is a problem with the `HorizontalLayoutGroup` component, in fact, removing it and arranging the objects "manually" does not meet this problem. However, the `HorizontalLayoutGroup` component is irreplaceable for arranging objects neatly on different screen aspect ratios. Can someone help me get the right `RectTrasnform` values ​​of the two buttons (which are the ones I actually see on the screen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html to get real world corner coorinates of your rects